# How can we add form-data and upload file in pact builder and content type is multipart/mixed?

Tags: pact

`form-data` to pass:

```
 -F "somepayload=
 {
    "messageId":"a00f9485-f8f3-4706-9a22",
    "orgId":"0025ba5f-4d00-bb7d",
    "userId":"806e4e3e-4af5-abbc",
    "recordingFormat": 
     {
       "fileType":"WAV",
       "encoding":"LINEAR16",
       "samplingRate":"8000",
       "bitsPerSample":"16"
     }
  };
  type=application/json" -F "uploadfile=@C:\Users\d1.wav
```

My Controller:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/check", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes =MediaType.MULTIPART_MIXED_VALUE)

 public String checkRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse, response) 
 {
   //codes
   return "success";
 }
```

My Pact builder:

```
 @Pact(consumer = "TestServer")
 public RequestResponsePact getVoiceRequest(PactDslWithProvider builder) 
 {
   return builder.given("")
    .uponReceiving("success")
    .method("POST")
    .headers(headers)
    .path("/audio-request")
    .willRespondWith()
    .status(200)
    .body(new PactDslJsonBody()
    // .stringValue("somepayload",
    // "{messageId:
    //    a00f9485-f8f3-4706-9a22-4497fa539c85,
    //    orgId:0025ba5f-96bc-4d00-bb7d-22406f62af17, 
    //    userId:806e4e3e-aaa7-4af5-abbc-ab4b56d66f60,
    //    recordingFormat:↵{fileType:WAV,
    //    encoding:LINEAR16,
    //    samplingRate:8000,
    //    bitsPerSample:16}
    //   }")
    .stringValue("messageId", "a00f9485-f8f3-4706-9a22-4497fa539c85")
    .stringValue("orgId","0025ba5f-96bc-4d00-bb7d-22406f62af17")
    .stringValue("userId","806e4e3e-aaa7-4af5-abbc-ab4b56d66f60"))
   .toPact();   
 }
```

I am not able to add form-data and file upload in my pact code here. Please suggest the methods which can be used.

Comment: I've done my best to format this so it's readable, but I wasn't sure about which stringValues you wanted commented out. So just left your example commented out. Hope that's right. If not, I think it should be easy enough for you to update.

Comment: Yes, its right, but the question is how to pass form-data  through Pact.